# A few questions about MediaPlayer in the Android SDK

Tags: android, mp3, media-player, android-mediaplayer

For some reason, I find some of the documentation unclear about the MediaPlayer (it's probably just me, as I'm new to the android SDK), but anyways...

Originally I thought that one MediaPlayer instance stored one track, but after noticing MediaPlayer#setTrack, I'm assuming one can store more than one track into a MediaPlayer object.

So here's my question, I have a file of MP3 files, how would I store all these MP3 files into a MediaPlayer object as tracks if possible? Would these MP3 files need to be stored into res/raw or the assets file?

Answer (score 0):

The MP3 files should go into your assets folder.

You should use setDataSource with the path to your mp3 file, something like this:

```
        String path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + mediafile;
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
```

Where 'mediafile' is the filename of your mp3 file.  That's how I did it anyway.

You can change the data source to play a different track, assuming you have a different mp3 file for each track.

Comment: Glad to help!  I see you are new to StackOverflow, so welcome to the community.  Don't forget to mark the correct answer (if there is one) by clicking the check mark (under the voting up/down arrows) and/or up voting the answers you like or find helpful.